# spring security http antMatcher with multiple paths

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following spring security java config rule (with version 3.2.4) which works:

```
http.antMatcher("/lti1p/**")
    .addFilterBefore(ltioAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("LTI")
    .and().csrf().disable();
```

However, I would like to apply this rule to 2 paths ("/lti1p/**" and ("/lti2p/**"). I can't just replace antMatcher with antMatchers (HttpSecurity object doesn't allow it) and when I try something like this it doesn't apply the rule correctly anymore.

```
http
    .addFilterBefore(ltioAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/lti1p/**","/lti2p/**").hasRole("LTI")
    .and().csrf().disable();
```

I have tried a number of variants of this without any luck. Does anyone know the correct way to apply this rule using java config to multiple paths?

Comment: Try this:
    `http
        .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/lti1p/**","/lti2p/**")
           .and()
        .addFilterBefore(ltioAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("LTI")
        .and().csrf().disable();`

Comment: That works. Please post the answer so I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
http 
  .requestMatchers()
       .antMatchers("/lti1p/**","/lti2p/**")
       .and()
  .addFilterBefore(ltioAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("LTI")
  .and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Any way to achieve the same thing with a `AntPathRequestMatcher` object ? So as to have a filter fire up only for a given path. I'd like to add another path to my filter configuration `@Bean
 public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
  AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter = new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login")));
  authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
  return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
 }`

Comment: What if we have multiple filters, each with its own path ? Are we forced to have an `http` configuration and its class for each filter ?

Comment: It it possible multiple paths to access to some urls with roles (admin e.g.), another must be only authenticated ? 
Like `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/users**", "/api/rest**").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority(Role.ROLE_ADMIN.getAuthority()).antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable()`. 
This doesn't work for `/api/**`

Answer (score -1):

try following :

```
 .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
            .antMatchers("/superadmin/**").hasRole("superadmin")
            .antMatchers("/billingmanager/**").hasAnyRole ( "billingmanager","admin")
            .antMatchers("/salesman/**").hasAnyRole ( "billingmanager","admin" ,"salesman")
            .antMatchers("/getjwttoken", "/healthcheck/**", "/registerultimateuser", "/test").permitAll()
```

//

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
.antMatchers("/lti1p/**").hasRole("LTI")
.antMatchers("/lti2p/**").hasRole("LTI")
```

Comment: Is that in the second one or did you mean to use antMatcher? Could you put the entire block in your answer?

Comment: Such approach doesn't work cause the second statement/pattern will replace the first one. By following the accepted answer is the right way to deal with multiple ant patterns