# permitAll() requires Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I'm having a go at developing a REST application with Spring and using JWT for authentication.

At the moment, what I'm trying to achieve is:

- `GET /api/subjects/*` should be accessible to all users.
- `POST /api/subjects/*` should only accessible to admin users.

The issue is that for both cases, the JWT filter gets invoked and I get an error response stating the JWT token is missing.

I've implemented my `WebSecurityConfig` as follows, including a JWT filter to replace the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    JWTAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/subjects/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/subjects/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/subjects/*").hasRole(Profile.Role.ADMIN.toString())
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .addFilterAt(authenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        return new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    public ProviderManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>(Arrays.asList(jwtAuthenticationProvider)));
    }
}
```

My implementation of `JWTAuthenticationFilter` is based on the implementation of `BasicAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String JWT_TOKEN_START = "JWT ";
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        Assert.notNull(authenticationManager, "Authentication Manager must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(authenticationEntryPoint, "Authentication Entry point must not be null");
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(JWT_TOKEN_START)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Header does not contain: \"Authorization\":\"JWT <token>\". Value: "+header);
        }

        try {
            String jwt = header.substring(JWT_TOKEN_START.length()).trim().replace("<", "").replace(">", "");
            JWTAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = new JWTAuthenticationToken(jwt);
            this.authenticationManager.authenticate(jwtAuthenticationToken);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        } catch (AuthenticationException auth) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            this.authenticationEntryPoint.commence(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, auth);
        }

    }
}
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring security http antMatcher with multiple paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234164/spring-security-http-antmatcher-with-multiple-paths)

Comment: Per the documentation:

`Invoking antMatcher(String) will override previous invocations of requestMatchers(), antMatcher(String), regexMatcher(String), and requestMatcher(RequestMatcher). ` You are overriding the former request matcher with the latter. Please follow the accepted answer here for resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234164/spring-security-http-antmatcher-with-multiple-paths

Comment: @Andonaeus: The example you show has different URLs. In my case, I have the same URLs but different HTTP methods. How would I structure my ant pattern in this case?