# antMatchers for a list of paths

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a list of paths which I want to provide to `antMatchers()`. But since this list is dynamic, I cannot provide paths comma separated. I am currently looping through the list and adding eachPath to `antMatcher()`. Is there a better way to do this where I can apply antMatcher to a list of paths?

Current Code snippet:

```
   http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/signup","/about")
    .hasRole("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

and I have a list of paths. For example:

```
List<String> pathList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"/signup","/about"});
```

and I want to apply the antMatchers something like:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(pathList)
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Reference: https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/
[spring security http antMatcher with multiple paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234164/spring-security-http-antmatcher-with-multiple-paths)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The antMatchers accepts string array.

```
public C antMatchers(String... antPatterns) {
 ....
}
```

You can convert the list to string array, and then pass it to the `antMatchers`,

```
String[] pathArray = new String[]{"/signup","/about"};
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(pathArray)
...
```